# Nsdata is not writing to file properly

Tags: objective-c

I have NSData object,it contains 16300 bytes and I am writing  to file. Write is success full. But once I want to read from path again, it gives me only 44 bytes.

```
//writing to path
[audioData writeToFile:recorderFilePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&err];
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"Error of writing to file %@",[err localizedDescription]);
    }
// reading from path
NSData *paddata =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Probably it didn't flush all the data yet. Try adding a delay before reading.

Comment: Can you see the size of the saved file to determine whether it's a write or a read problem?

Comment: What are the values of `recorderFilePath` and `filePath`?

Comment: @Mats values are same for both.

Comment: @ppaulojr I am not reading data immediately after write operation. And If I add delay here it may cause race conditions.

Comment: FYI - your code for checking the error is incorrect. It should be: `if (![audioData writeToFile:recorderFilePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&err]) { NSLog(@"Error of writing to file %@",[err localizedDescription]); }`. Always check the return value of the method to determine if there was an error or not.

Comment: @rmaddy hi,thank you. but my problem is not that.

Comment: It might have been because you aren't actually checking to see if the call to `writeToFile:` was succeeding or not.

Answer (score -1):

> Just below code used for write your audio file and read from path.
>
> Write audio file to path

[fileData writeToFile:audioFilePath atomically:YES];

> reading from path

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];